# JQuery, AJAX: Can't insert data from form and return to same page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, insert

I'm trying to insert information from a form into a database table and then return to the same page with a success or failure alert message. I can't seem to get it to work however. Here's what I currently have...

HTML FORM

```
  <form id="add-menu-item">
     <input type="text" name="name" class="formbox">
      <input type="text" name="price" class="formbox">
  <input type="submit" class="form-submit-button">
  </form>
```

JQUERY

```
    $("#add-menu-item").click(function()
    {
        addMenuItem();

    });

function addMenuItem()
{
    var t_name    = $("#add-menu-item [name='name']").val();
    var t_price   = $("#add-menu-item [name='price']").val();
    var errors  = '';

    $.ajax({
        type    : "GET",
        url     : "insert.php",
        data    : { name  : t_name,
                    price : t_price, },
        cache   : false, timeout: 10000,

        success  : function() {
            alert("WORKED!");
        },
        error    : function() {
            alert("DIDN'T WORK!");
        },
        complete : function() {
        }
    });
});
```

INSERT.php

```
<?php

include_once('_code/connectdb.php');
include_once('_code/functions.php');

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
$error = '';

$query = "INSERT INTO menuitems ( name, price ) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$price}')";

if (!mysql_query($query, $conn))
{
    $error = mysql_error();
    $return['error'] = $error;
    echo json_encode($return);
    mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
    $success = "Menu Item Successfully Added!";
    $return['mysql'] = $success;
   echo json_encode($return);
    mysql_close($conn);
}

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Solved the problem. the "});" at the end of addMenuItem() was wrong shoul've been "}" ;( Thanks everyone sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what doesn't work. However I think:

```
$("#add-menu-item").click(function() {
  addMenuItem();
});
```

Should be:

```
$("#add-menu-item").submit(function() { // you want the action to perform on submit of form and not on click??? on form
  addMenuItem();
  return false; // to prevent submitting the form after ajax stuff is done
});
```

And I think:

```
data    : { name  : t_name,
                    price : t_price, },
```

Should be:

```
data: ({name : t_name, price : t_price}),
```

Don't know the last one for sure though: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#example-5

Answer (score 1):

Use fireBug or similar software to detect this type of errors easly......................